# Can't get PouchDB authentication working

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I've tried numerous configurations but failed to make this Karma/Jasmine unit test pass.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Running CouchDb 1.6.1 . Jasmine unit test is running inside IntelliJ IDEA.

```
describe("CouchDb Auth")      
  it("Test login", function (done) {

    var auth = {
      username: 'demo',
      password: 'omed'
    }

    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/demo';

    var ajaxOpts = {
      headers: {
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(auth.username + ':' + auth.password),
      }
    };

    var db = new PouchDB(url, {skipSetup: true});

    db.login(auth.username, auth.password, ajaxOpts)
      .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    done();
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);

    done('Failed to login');
      });
  });
});
```

`local.ini`  File:  Couch 1.6.1

```
[couchdb]
;max_document_size = 4294967296 ; bytes
uuid = 3fe8f6afb42b8fde93b8b66818b3476c

[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
enable_cors = true

; Uncomment next line to trigger basic-auth popup on unauthorized requests.
WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"
; WWW-Authenticate = Other realm="app"

[cors]
; You can’t set origins: * and credentials = true at the same time.
credentials = true
; List of origins separated by a comma, * means accept all
; Origins must include the scheme: http://example.com
origins = http://localhost:9876
; List of accepted headers separated by a comma
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, cache-control, x-requested-with, x-csrf-token
; List of accepted methods
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE

[couch_httpd_auth]
secret = somesecretstuff
require_valid_user = true

[log]
level = debug

[ssl]
;cert_file = /full/path/to/server_cert.pem
;key_file = /full/path/to/server_key.pem
;password = somepassword
; set to true to validate peer certificates
verify_ssl_certificates = false
; Path to file containing PEM encoded CA certificates (trusted
; certificates used for verifying a peer certificate). May be omitted if
; you do not want to verify the peer.
;cacert_file = /full/path/to/cacertf
; The verification fun (optional) if not specified, the default
; verification fun will be used.
;verify_fun = {Module, VerifyFun}
; maximum peer certificate depth
ssl_certificate_max_depth = 1

[vhosts]

[update_notification]

[admins]
;admin = mysecretpassword

; demo = omed
demo = -pbkdf2-606718f546624acae3a7ed561540352921281e7c,a1d619524376dfbd0f8f6547856d74eb,10
```

Answer (score 2):

pouchdb-authentication is actually designed to use *cookie authentication*, not *HTTP authentication* (i.e. the `Authorization` header). Calling `db.login()` should be good enough, because it will set the cookie for you.

If you are unsure why this is failing, I recommend just running the pouchdb-authentication test suite in your own browser against your own CouchDB, so you can try to figure out whether the problem is in your Nginx layer, your CouchDB configuration, your pouchdb-authentication configuration, etc. To do so, it's just:

```
git clone https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication.git
cd pouchdb-authentication
npm install
npm run dev
```

Then open http://127.0.0.1:8002/test/index.html in a browser. It will try to authenticate with localhost:5984.

Comment: Thanks will run your unit tests. I've just reinstalled my CouchDb server to be certain. and am writing small incremental unit tests but your test suite sounds smarter.  Thanks yet again!  Hope I get to shake your hand one day in person.

Comment: I've based this code on your example which uses additional Basic Auth for 1st call to avoid pop up pain.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP authentication**

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/src/adapters/http/index.js

```
 if (opts.auth || host.auth) {
      var nAuth = opts.auth || host.auth;
      var token = btoa(nAuth.username + ':' + nAuth.password);
      ajaxOpts.headers = ajaxOpts.headers || {};
      ajaxOpts.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + token;
 }
```

so ajaxOpts should be

```
 var ajaxOpts = {
      auth: {
           username:'...',
           password:'...'    
      }          
 };
```

Works on phonegap, with no cookies.

Comment: Yep .. Done all that.  This was more likely a server config issue.